# how do i copy to clipboard with the input or placeholder name?

Tags: javascript, forms, button, onclick, clipboard

I have a simple form: https://jsfiddle.net/skootsa/8j0ycvsp/6/

```
<div class='field'>
<input placeholder='Nickname' type='text'>
</div>
<div class='field'>
<input placeholder='Age' type='text'>
</div>
```

How would I get a button that copied the contents of each input box + the "placeholder" attribute (or class name)? So that the clipboard results looked like this:

> Nickname: Johnnyboy
>
> Age: 22

Comment: Probably duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. create an invisible element to copy the data
2. get the data from your form and set it to the previous element
3. select it
4. call `document.execCommand('copy')` to copy the selected text to the
   clipboard

I have updated your fiddle, check it out https://jsfiddle.net/8j0ycvsp/9/

In case you want the code

```
function copyToClipboard() {

    /*get inputs from form */
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#the-form input[type=text]");

    /*do a copy of placeholder and contents*/
    var clipboardText = ''
    for (var i = 0, input; input = inputs[i++];) {
        clipboardText += input.placeholder+': '+(input.value ? input.value : '' )+'\n';     
    }

    /*create hidden textarea with the content and select it*/
    var clipboard = document.createElement("textarea");
    clipboard.style.height = 0;
    clipboard.style.width  = 0;
    clipboard.value = clipboardText;
    document.body.appendChild(clipboard);
    clipboard.select();

    console.log(clipboard.value);

    /*do a copy fren*/
    try {
        if(document.execCommand('copy'))
            console.log('Much succes, wow!');
        else 
            console.log('Very fail, wow!');

    } catch (err) {        
        console.log('Heckin concern, unable to copy');
    }
}
```

Comment: its not updating my clipboard for some reason

Comment: @amy-gr8njr I've added the code and updated the fiddle. Javascript Load Type needed to be "No wrap - in <head>" in the fiddle example. Should work now!

Answer (score 0):

So give it a try

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll('.field input');

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
 var innerHTMLText = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  innerHTMLText += input[i].placeholder + ':' + input[i].value + '      ';
 }
 console.log(innerHTMLText);
 document.getElementsByClassName('bix')[0].innerHTML = innerHTMLText;
});
```