# HTML/CSS input placeholder text which can be copied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to find anything similar to this right now, but I am pretty sure I have seen something like it before.

I am currently able to use either input or textarea html tags and the placeholder attribute to get something close to what I want, but I also want to provide the user the ability to copy the placeholder text and enter/paste it in the same box as an entry. Is this possible?

An use case would be a place holder of a common directory path:
box1@mtk:/path/to/data/20180202_TextFile.txt

I want the user to be able to copy and paste "box1@mtk:/path/to/data/" into the box so they just have to change the text file name.

I can't force value to be the placeholder because I don't want users accidentally submitting forms without modifying all fields.

So is it possible to have selectable / copyable placeholders?

Comment: Doesn't this helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568404/how-do-i-copy-to-clipboard-with-the-input-or-placeholder-name

Comment: In a word, no. They would not be placeholder attributes at that point. You could use what's in the linked answer from @ClaudioNastasiJunior, but that's kind of messy. I'd just have the text in the text box, add an `input` event handler to flag that the user has touched the value, and if not, don't enable the submit button.

Comment: Why not just make that text the default `value` of the input?

Comment: is there a certain event you want to bind to? Like a button press or focus or something?

Comment: I feel like it might be easier to have a button next to the box that says "default"

Comment: Agree with Marcus. Just set the input default value...you can also change its color to look like a placeholder. You can even make it disappear when user clicks on it, and provide a button if user wants to accept "placeholder" value.

Answer (score 0):

No you have to choose between placeholder and value. I would just use value in combination with a script that enables the button when all the fields are different from their default value or prints an error message if they are not eg:

```
if(document.getElementById(“value1”).value !== “DEFAULT TEXT” && document.getElementById(“value2”).value !== “DEFAULT TEXT” && ......) {
    document.getElementById(“submit”).disabled = false;
}
```